# How can I execute a python script from php and send a curl request from python?

Tags: php, python, xampp, ubuntu-18.04

I want to execute a python script from php script which will send a curl request to a web api and will return the output of the curl request to php script which will print it or do further processing.The problem is when I run the python script independently it produces correct output but when it is called from php script it doesn't work

I have tried changing permissions for the htdocs folder on xampp server and since I thought the image file which is being uploaded to server via api request is not accessible.

This is the part of php script which executes the python script

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    sleep(5);
    $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/script.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
}
```

This is the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import ast
import requests
from time import sleep
import datetime
file = open('/opt/lampp/htdocs/count.txt','r')
uid=file.read().strip()
file.close()
print(uid)
pipe = subprocess.Popen('curl -X POST "https://api- 
us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect" -F 
"api_key=some_key" \
-F "api_secret=some_key" \
-F "image_file=@/opt/lamppp/htdocs/image.jpg"', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, 
universal_newlines=True)
j = pipe.stdout.readlines()
print(j)
```

Expected output should print something like this when php page is called.

['{"image_id": "mprd5Pjd9ni+sPD4fWzv9g==", "request_id": "1554044606,8bba1d32-9b73-4457-a024-cb3ad66ee349", "time_used": 623, "faces": [{"face_rectangle": {"width": 134, "top": 159, "left": 242, "height": 134}, "face_token": "a0bc6e53782d0c38a837187a832da542"}]}'

but it prints empty sqaure braces.[]

Comment: In my language we like to say "from behind through the chest into the eye" if some overcomplicates things.

Comment: Why don't you do the curl call within php?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make a CURL request you would be better off just using PHP's builtin CURL functions to keep your code less complex (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

But if you still want to use the python script, then things to check are

- The script is executable by the XAMPP user
- You have the python SHEBANG on the first line of the python script  `#!/usr/bin/env python` ([see explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt/2429517#2429517))
- Python is apart of the XAMPP users PATH (or use the full path instead of python in shell_exec)

Other than that, you can try using `exec` instead of `shell_exec` since `shell_exec` wont return a value if an error is thrown

```
$command = 'python /scripts/some_script.py';
$response = [];
$code = 0;
exec($command, $response, $code);
var_dump($code);
print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a shell file to execute your python script and make sure it's executable , Then make PHP to execute this shell file .

**It Works For Me**